# Can I use a String as a WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, jsp

Can anybody help me with this JSP problem. 
Im trying to update the database using code similar to this:

So, I have this on my Servlet:

```
String QueryCondition = "id = 1";
```

That will be passed to this stored procedure:

```
CREATE 
    DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
    PROCEDURE `storedprocedure_1`(QueryCondition TEXT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE users SET name = 'John'
    WHERE QueryCondition;
END
```

I was thinking if this is possible because the update always fail.
If this isn't possible can you recommend how can i do such thing

Comment: you can pass this in your query string it will get passed as a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in a stored procedure but with a prepared statement.

**Example**:

```
DELIMITER //

CREATE 
  DEFINER=root@localhost 
  PROCEDURE storedprocedure_1(QueryCondition TEXT) 
BEGIN 
  SET @query := CONCAT( 'UPDATE users SET name = \'John\' WHERE ',
                        QueryCondition );

  PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DROP PREPARE stmt;
END;
//

DELIMITER ;
```